# open keyboard in OnViewCreated

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a fragment with an EditText inside, I just want to open keyboard automatically when i arrive in this fragment but I can't find the way.

I think java provide a way to do this but can't find myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can request focus in onViewCreated()

```java
.....
 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.et);
    editText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) 
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
...
```

Comment: this put the marker on my editText but doesn't open my keyboard, may miss something ?

Comment: can you try now

Comment: Still the the same, what is the "edit" in the showSoftInput?

Comment: replace the list line `imgr.showSoftInput()` with  `imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
`

Comment: Aha now I need to know how to close it in my OnClick ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in onCreateView() method in your fragment

```
    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```

or use ,

```
android:focusable="true"
```

in your editext in xml